# Can't install deluge

Tags: deluge

I'm trying to install deluge through `synaptic package manager` but I got problem:

```
deluge:
 Depends: python-libtorrent but it is not going to be installed
```

I have tried reinstall python-libtorrent by apt-get and also I got problem:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-libtorrent : Depends: libtorrent-rasterbar6 (= 0.15.7-1) but 0.15.9+svn.r6292-0ubuntu1~natty is to be installed
```

How actually I can install deluge? Thanks

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If the package `libtorrent-rasterbar6` is already installed, try reinsalling it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libtorrent-rasterbar6
```

---

First install `libtorrent-rasterbar6`:

```
sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar6
```

Then install `python-libtorrent`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libtorrent
```

And then install `deluge`:

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
```

**Note:** If you find any other dependencies at any stage, install them first.

Comment: libtorrent-rasterbar6 was already installed, while installing python-libtorrent i've got the same error "The following ..."

Comment: try removing libtorrent-rasterbar6 and installing again.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was fixed with activating Canonical Partners in the other software tab from the menu of Ubuntu Software.
Do not forget to let it update, or run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall deluge
```

will fix things.

Comment: why don't don't you put the steps to __enable__ the __repositories__.

Answer (score 1):

Here what works for me :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libtorrent.org/rc-1.1-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-libtorrent
sudo apt-get install deluge
```